# How can I get my cupboard doors to close after installing new hinges?

Tags: hinges

I'm installing NEW hinges and painting cupboards.  I could not find hinges that matched the old 28 year old ones, so have new hinges.  These are not hinges that have the part that goes into the wood - they're just plain hinges.  However, once installed in what appears to be the correct location, the doors refuse to stay shut.  They pop open about an inch.  It would seem that maybe the hinges are too tight, but I can't figure this out at all. I can't leave them as is, because it's even more unsightly than before.  Called a male friend who has a lot of mechanical/handyman/household experience, and he couldn't figure it out either.  I hate to hammer on these new hinges and make things worse.  Suggestions?

Comment: Post a picture for better advice.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing how a hinge is mounted on the door and on the cabinet. Pictures will help us help you. Also, it will help if we know the hinge manufacturer and model number.

Answer (score 3):

Plain hinges with no springs cannot keep doors snug up against the cabinet even under the best conditions. At best the doors sort of "float" near the fully closed position. More often than not the doors drift open slightly. You need some sort of catch to use with plain hinges. There many sorts, usually relying on some sort of spring or magnetic device to hold the door closed but release easily when pulled upon.